# XPath получить номер узла и умножить

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

Структура XML

```
<main>
  <Set>
    <Name>...</Name>
    <Items Seek="10">
      <Item Pos="18" /> <!-- 10 * 1 -->
      <Item Pos="112" /> <!-- 10 * 2 -->
      <Item Pos="29" /> <!-- 10 * 3 -->
    </Items>
  </Set>
  <Set>
    <Name>...</Name>
    <Items Seek="20">
      <Item Pos="18" /> <!-- 20 * 1 -->
      <Item Pos="5" /> <!-- 20 * 2 -->
      <Item Pos="2" /> <!-- 20 * 3 -->
    </Nums>
  </Set>
</main>
```

Как составить Xpath запрос чтоб он возвращал произведение Seek на позицию элемента Item, мне нужно узнать на сколько смещен каждый Item в отдельности.

Нет большого опыта работы с Xpath, поэтому не знаю с чего начать и возможно ли это вообще чтоб зря время не терять.

Comment: А причём тут WPF?

Comment: XPath это язык для выборки элементов. С его помощью можно выбрать Set, Name, Item, их аттрибуты - уже существующие ноды xml. Но с его помощью нельзя выбрать "произведение чего-то на чего-то" - потому что произведения нет в оригинальном xml.

Comment: Хотел добавить этот запрос в Binding XPath

Answer (score 3):

Выбрать несколько "произведений" с помощью XPath на C# нельзя. Можно использовать xslt для преобразования оригинального xml в что-то вроде

```
<Items>
  <Item SeekMultiplied="10" />
  <Item SeekMultiplied="20" />
  <Item SeekMultiplied="30" />
  <Item SeekMultiplied="20" />
  <Item SeekMultiplied="40" />
  <Item SeekMultiplied="60" />
</Items>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="main">
    <Items>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Items>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//Item">
    <Item>
      <xsl:attribute name="SeekMultiplied">
        <xsl:value-of select="../@Seek * (count(preceding-sibling::Item) + 1)"/>
      </xsl:attribute> 
    </Item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text() | @*">
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Код для его вызова на C#:

```
var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(@"C:\Temp\1.xslt");

var transforResult = new XmlDocument();
using (var navigator = transforResult.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
{
    transform.Transform(@"C:\Temp\input.xml", navigator);
}
```

но в вашем случае гораздо проще сделать то же самое на чистом C#.

Comment: Вроде Wikipedia говорит что Xpath есть числовые функции https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath#.D0.A7.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.84.D1.83.D0.BD.D0.BA.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B8

Comment: @Event есть. но результатом вычисления XPath в C# может быть или набор нод (если вызывать его через SelectNodes) или одна строка/число/bool (если вызывать через CreateNavigator.Evaludate()). Для одной конкретной ноды выражение есть в ответе - `../@Seek * (count(preceding-sibling::Item) + 1)`. Но выдаст оно ровно одно число.

Answer (score 0):

если надо вычислить значения и изменить теги, то так:

```csharp
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
// ...
var xe = XElement.Parse(@"
         <Set>
           <Items Seek='10'>
             <Item Pos='18' />
             <Item Pos='112' />
             <Item Pos='29' />
           </Items>
         </Set>");
var item = XName.Get("Item");
var seek = XName.Get("Seek");
foreach (var n in xe.Descendants(item)) {
    var c = n.ElementsBeforeSelf().Count() + 1;
    var s = n.Parent.Attribute(seek);
    n.Add(s.Value + " * " + c);
}
Console.WriteLine(xe);
```

результат

```
<Set>
  <Items Seek="10">
    <Item Pos="18">10*1</Item>
    <Item Pos="112">10*2</Item>
    <Item Pos="29">10*3</Item>
  </Items>
</Set>
```

Answer (score 0):

если надо только вычислить значения для всех Item'ов, то можно использовать XPathExpression и XPathNavigator.

```csharp
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
// ...
var xe = XElement.Parse(@"
<Set>
    <Items Seek='10'>
        <Item Pos='18' />
        <Item Pos='112' />
        <Item Pos='29' />
    </Items>
</Set>");
var xn = xe.CreateNavigator();
var item = xn.Compile("//Item");
var result = xn.Compile("(count(preceding-sibling::Item) + 1) * parent::*/@Seek");
var s = xn.Select(item);
while (s.MoveNext()) {
    var v = (double) s.Current.Evaluate(result);
    Console.WriteLine(v);
}
```

результат

```
10
20
30
```